# How can I get past a “Repository is not signed…” message when attempting to upgrade Kali Linux from a mounted disk image?

Tags: kali-linux, apt

I am trying to upgrade Kali Linux from 2017.2 to 2018.2 using an iso mounted in the Kali Virtual Machine.

So, what I did was I edited my `sources.list` file to:

```
deb file:///media/cdrom0 kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

and commented other lines using #.

Now, whenever I try `apt-get update`, I get:

```
E: The repository 'file:/media/cdrom0 kali-rolling Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

According to [the Debian man page for `apt-get`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-get.8.en.html), you can use the `--allow-unauthenticated` option like this:

```
apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated
```

As the man page entry for `--allow-unauthenticated` explains:

> Ignore if packages can't be authenticated and don't prompt about it. This can be useful while working with local repositories, but is a huge security risk if data authenticity isn't ensured in another way by the user itself. The usage of the Trusted option for sources.list(5) entries should usually be preferred over this global override. Configuration Item: APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated.

And if that doesn’t work, try run-in it with `--allow-insecure-repositories` like this:

```
apt-get update --allow-insecure-repositories
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work. However, in the manual, I saw in 'man apt-secure' that we can force using '--allow-insecure-repositories' which did the trick, but unfortunately, there were other errors. Thanks for the effort btw.

Answer (score 27):

You should tell apt it's a trusted source:

```
deb [trusted=yes] file:/media/cdrom0 kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone like me that came across this because their repository is not signed. Maybe on another distro not specifically Kali Linux.

My distro in question was MX linux.

I found this command to import the missing gpg keys.

```
checkaptgpg
```