# Kali apt-get update fails with "Clearsigned file isn't valid"

Tags: updates, kali-linux, sudo, apt

I'm trying to do apt-get update at in result i am getting these errors, tried various methods, couldnt resolve. i need help with this error.

```
Get:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease [18.3 kB]
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Reading package lists... Done        
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

The `ls` results of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` are:

```
00aptitude      00trustcdrom  02autoremove-postgresql  50command-not-found  70debconf
00CDMountPoint  01autoremove  50apt-file.conf          50kali               80debtags
```

My Kali is a virtual machine on MacOS silicon version.
Output of `cat /etc/os-release`:

```
{PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
VERSION="2022.4"
VERSION_ID="2022.4"
VERSION_CODENAME="kali-rolling"
ID=kali
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.kali.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.kali.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.kali.org/"
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"}
```

Results of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
{# See https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

# Additional line for source packages
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free}
```

`ls` of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` just shows nothing.

Comment: In order to provide an answer we need the contents of `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment. If you use a proxy we need to know. also provide `/etc/apt/sources.list` in the same edit

Comment: That seems odd, my result is `Get:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease [41.2 kB]`. Is this on hardware or a Virtual Machine? Can you please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1774745/edit) your question and add outputs of `cat /etc/os-release`, `cat /etc/sources.list` and `ls /etc/sources.list.d`? Please enclose the outputs in the code brackets `{ }` to preserve the formatting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get past a “Repository is not signed…” message when attempting to upgrade Kali Linux from a mounted disk image?](https://superuser.com/questions/1331936/how-can-i-get-past-a-repository-is-not-signed-message-when-attempting-to-upgr)

Comment: The curly brackets look wrong; are those really part of the output, or your attempt at formatting the question?

Comment: the curly brackets are not part of outputs i just added to explain output inside of it.

Comment: You can use `apt-get --print-uris update` to get the exact URL for the download, and then, just for diagnostic, not for use, download it with curl or wget. You should then examine the content. Maybe there's a (transparent-)proxy error instead of a correct content? Without signature, you can't trust its content. Don't accept any answer explaining how to circumvent a verification.